# A query that can count the occurrences of every teacher?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

so I'm a student and I'm currently working on a project where I need to assign teachers to courses. Every Teacher has a first,second and third choice and a teaching load for every semester.
I'm working on Access and currently focused on Winter(for semester)

I tried this query but the count(Schedule.Faculty) shows 1 for everyone which is the value of test2 , is there an easy way to make it count the value of every teacher on its own ?

I appreciate your help.

the query:

```
SELECT Courses.Reference, First([Classes : Full-Time].Faculty) as Faculty,Year(Date()) as Year,'Winter' as Semester,count(Schedule.Faculty) as count FROM Courses, [Faculty : Full-Time], [Classes : Full-Time],Schedule
WHERE (((Courses.[Every Winter])=True) AND (([Faculty : Full-Time].[E-mail])=[Classes : Full-Time].[Faculty]) AND (([Faculty : Full-Time].Availability)=True) AND (([Classes : Full-Time].[First Choice])=True) AND (([Classes : Full-Time].Reference)=[Courses].[Reference])) OR ((([Faculty : Full-Time].[E-mail])=[Classes : Full-Time].[Faculty]) AND (([Faculty : Full-Time].Availability)=True) AND (([Classes : Full-Time].[First Choice])=True) AND (([Classes : Full-Time].Reference)=[Courses].[Reference]) AND (((Year(Date())) Mod (2))=0) AND ((Courses.[Every Winter (even)])=True)) OR ((([Faculty : Full-Time].[E-mail])=[Classes : Full-Time].[Faculty]) AND (([Faculty : Full-Time].Availability)=True) AND (([Classes : Full-Time].[First Choice])=True) AND (([Classes : Full-Time].Reference)=[Courses].[Reference]) AND (((Year(Date())) Mod (2))<>0) AND ((Courses.[Every Winter (odd)])=True)) and (Schedule.Faculty=[Classes : Full-Time].Faculty)
GROUP BY Courses.Reference,Schedule.Faculty
having count(Schedule.Faculty)<(select [Teaching Load (Winter)] from [Faculty : Full-Time] where [Faculty : Full-Time].[E-mail] = Schedule.Faculty);
```

the Schedule table:

```
Course Teacher
123    test1 
124    test1
125    test2
```

what I get:

```
123 test1 1
125 test2 1
```

meanwhile it should be 2 for test1.

The table courses has the course reference, and when it is taught
The [Classes : Full-Time] table has the faculty e-mail and what they teach and if that course is their first/second or third choice

I'm only showing the value so that I know it's doing the right calculation, I will need the right teachers to be selected so that I can insert them in the table.

Comment: Edit question to show what you want as output.

Comment: Also, show sample data for all tables involved.